# Does the Query time include the Lock time in mysql?

Tags: mysql, optimization

If I see in the mysql_slow.log file this info:

```
Query_time: 31.112148  Lock_time: 31.111902 
Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1 SET timestamp=1380118248;
```

Does it means that the total time wastes for that specific query it was Query_time - Lock_time = 0.000246?

Or does the specific query wastes the Query_time and the whole process wasted Query_time + Lock_time = 62.22405?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first guess was right; the execution time on the query was 0.000246.

The `Lock_time` represents how long the query spent **waiting to acquire a lock**, whether the lock was just on the row (for tables using the InnoDB storage engine) or on the entire table (MyISAM storage engine).

To reduce the `Lock_time`, you can consider changing the storage engine of your table to InnoDB, which supports the locking of individual rows during `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and other statements which modify the content of the database. MyISAM locks the entire table for such operations.